# Javascript - scroll direction Detect in addEventListener 'scroll'

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouselistener

I have Fixed Header ,That Work With Mouse Scroll
How Change This code That Work only With Scroll UP

```
function init() {
                    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
                        if( !didScroll ) {
                            didScroll = true;
                            setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 ); //Scroll Page
                        }
                    }, false );
                }
```

//Scroll Function

```
                function scrollPage() {
                    var sy = scrollY();                      

                    if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
                        if(!$('.template-content').hasClass('fixed-active') && (!$('.header-wrapper').hasClass('slider-overlap') || $('body').hasClass('breadcrumbs-type-9') || $('body').hasClass('breadcrumbs-type-default')) )
                        etTheme.headerHeight('set');
                        classie.add( wrapper, 'fixed-active' );
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            classie.add( wrapper, 'fixed-active-animate' );
                        },250);
                    }
                    else {
                        classie.remove( wrapper, 'fixed-active' );
                        classie.remove( wrapper, 'fixed-active-animate' );
                        etTheme.headerHeight('unset');
                    }
                    didScroll = false;
                }
```

//Scroll Position

```
                function scrollY() {
                    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
                }
```

//Call Function

```
                init();
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more?

Answer (score 0):

```
function scrollPage() {
                    var sy = scrollY();
                    if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn && LastscrollY > sy) {
                        if(!$('.template-content').hasClass('fixed-active') && (!$('.header-wrapper').hasClass('slider-overlap') || $('body').hasClass('breadcrumbs-type-9') || $('body').hasClass('breadcrumbs-type-default')) )
                        etTheme.headerHeight('set');
                        classie.add( wrapper, 'fixed-active' );
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            classie.add( wrapper, 'fixed-active-animate' );
                        },250); //150
                    }
                    else {
                        classie.remove( wrapper, 'fixed-active' );
                        classie.remove( wrapper, 'fixed-active-animate' );
                        etTheme.headerHeight('unset');
                    }
                    didScroll = false;
                    LastscrollY = sy;
                }
```

Comment: This really  should be an update to your question.  While you are updating your question, though, it would help if you created a snippet that showed the actual problem in a way we could all run.  There is a 'snippet' button in the toolbar when you edit the question.